# Azure Sql Reporting Service external Image

Tags: sql, image, azure, reporting

We are working on Sql Azure Reporting Services, we have a situation where we need to display client logo on report. We are passing Image path (URL) as parameter to the report which works fine on normal windows server reporting services, but when we move to Sql Azure Reporting it fails to show image on report e.g. image path can be like "http://p.lui.li/img-30718_images_j-r-full.jpg". Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell this is currently not supported in Azure SQL Reporting.  I tried it in a sample report and I couldn't get it to work even if I use Azure Blob storage.  You can upload the image to the reporting server as an alternative but external linking is still not implemented.  I would vote here:

http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/169380-business-analytics-sql-reporting/suggestions/2395600-support-external-image-in-reporting-services

This was similar to the Azure CORS problem that is finally going to be fixed soon.  The nice thing is when they finally fix it you will get notified if you vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by moving the image to Azure Sql Server Database, and then populating the image from database resolved the issue.